# Excel searching teams

Tags: excel, email, search, automation, microsoft-teams

I need to to get excel to search teams for an email address. Is this possible.
What I would have is a column, say column A. It would be a list of names format last, first. Can I set up excel to search teams with that cell data and if there is a match return the listed email address.

I haven't written anything, I have no idea where to begin or if this is even possible. If not I will need to rethink this process. We already get a long list of names and the idea is to save time searching each one manually.

Comment: Are you developing any Microsoft Teams app?

Comment: Yes, learn the vlookup function. Also Index and Match function can be very helpful. Or the xlookup function.